# App crash UIFoundation: UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 424

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, crash

I have created app on swift. And when i present one of view controllers app crashes. Note: When i run it dirrectly from xcode on my device there is no crash. But when i run it from testflight app crashes.
I have created tab bar with 5 tabs. and when i open one of tabs this happens
 Crash log is attached.

```
Incident Identifier: D22BDFF9-0A5F-42F5-A218-88A539CEAC82
Beta Identifier:     32829F50-1396-44EE-9548-EC4629A3D173
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,1
Process:             auction.ios [11622]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/964E0B80-C99A-4D24-9BEF-B5FAD27C2FD8/auction.ios.app/auction.ios
Identifier:          
Version:             1 (1.0)
AppStoreTools:       11C29
AppVariant:          1:iPhone12,1:13
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.auction.haraj [6076]


Date/Time:           2020-03-20 22:56:22.3571 +0200
Launch Time:         2020-03-20 22:56:12.1205 +0200
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.3.1 (17D50)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    1.04.06
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1ba53c96c __exceptionPreprocess + 224 (NSException.m:199)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ba255028 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1ba42c14c +[NSException raise:format:] + 112 (NSException.m:155)
3   UIFoundation                    0x1bdb8410c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 412 (UINibDecoder.m:695)
4   UIFoundation                    0x1bdb84480 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1296 (UINibDecoder.m:611)
5   UIFoundation                    0x1bdb1f00c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 320 (UINibDecoder.m:811)
6   UIKitCore                       0x1beabf488 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 788 (UIView.m:4240)
7   UIKitCore                       0x1be7d02b8 -[UITableViewCellContentView initWithCoder:] + 48 (UITableViewCellContentView.m:52)
8   UIFoundation                    0x1bdb8424c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 732 (UINibDecoder.m:717)
9   UIFoundation                    0x1bdb84480 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1296 (UINibDecoder.m:611)
10  UIFoundation                    0x1bdb1f00c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 320 (UINibDecoder.m:811)
11  UIKitCore                       0x1beabf488 -[UIView initWithCoder:] + 788 (UIView.m:4240)
12  UIKitCore                       0x1be7bed60 -[UITableViewCell initWithCoder:] + 100 (UITableViewCell.m:1573)
13  auction.ios                     0x1041130a8 0x1040e0000 + 209064
14  UIKitCore                       0x1be2c5818 -[UIClassSwapper initWithCoder:] + 2364 (UIClassSwapper.m:157)
15  UIFoundation                    0x1bdb8424c UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 732 (UINibDecoder.m:717)
16  UIFoundation                    0x1bdb84480 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 1296 (UINibDecoder.m:611)
17  UIFoundation                    0x1bdb1f00c -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 320 (UINibDecoder.m:811)
18  UIKitCore                       0x1be2c7568 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1180 (UINib.m:348)
19  UIKitCore                       0x1be814714 -[UITableView _dequeueReusableViewOfType:withIdentifier:] + 596 (UITableView.m:8575)
20  auction.ios                     0x104122534 0x1040e0000 + 271668
21  auction.ios                     0x1041227e4 0x1040e0000 + 272356
22  UIKitCore                       0x1be82d5d0 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 644 (UITableView.m:14483)
23  UIKitCore                       0x1be7fa088 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2592 (UITableView.m:2934)
24  UIKitCore                       0x1be817838 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 164 (UITableView.m:9240)
25  UIKitCore                       0x1beaf08b0 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2156 (UIView.m:17028)
26  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ba250a4c -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 68 (NSObject.mm:2182)
27  QuartzCore                      0x1c110655c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 292 (CALayer.mm:9627)
28  QuartzCore                      0x1c11069ac CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 484 (CALayer.mm:9501)
29  QuartzCore                      0x1c11191bc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 140 (CALayer.mm:2461)
30  QuartzCore                      0x1c105db00 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double) + 308 (CAContextInternal.mm:1992)
31  QuartzCore                      0x1c1088910 CA::Transaction::commit() + 684 (CATransactionInternal.mm:438)
32  UIKitCore                       0x1be636224 _UIApplicationFlushRunLoopCATransactionIfTooLate + 116 (UIApplication.m:2987)
33  UIKitCore                       0x1be6d3314 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5700 (UIEventDispatcher.m:2037)
34  UIKitCore                       0x1be6cc194 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 112 (UIEventDispatcher.m:1976)
35  CoreFoundation                  0x1ba4b8108 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1922)
36  CoreFoundation                  0x1ba4b805c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 84 (CFRunLoop.c:1956)
37  CoreFoundation                  0x1ba4b77c8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 184 (CFRunLoop.c:1992)
38  CoreFoundation                  0x1ba4b2694 __CFRunLoopRun + 1068 (CFRunLoop.c:2882)
39  CoreFoundation                  0x1ba4b1f40 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480 (CFRunLoop.c:3192)
40  GraphicsServices                0x1c4742534 GSEventRunModal + 108 (GSEvent.c:2246)
41  UIKitCore                       0x1be63d580 UIApplicationMain + 1940 (UIApplication.m:4773)
42  auction.ios                     0x1040e61c8 0x1040e0000 + 25032
43  libdyld.dylib                   0x1ba330e18 start + 4

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001ba326efc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001ba2468b8 pthread_kill + 228 (pthread.c:1458)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001ba1d6a74 abort + 104 (abort.c:110)
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ba2ee3c8 abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:76)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ba2ee5c0 demangling_terminate_handler() + 308 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:66)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ba255308 _objc_terminate() + 124 (objc-exception.mm:701)
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ba2fb634 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x00000001ba2fb1ec __cxa_rethrow + 148 (cxa_exception.cpp:618)
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001ba2551ec objc_exception_rethrow + 44 (objc-exception.mm:604)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ba4b1fb0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 592 (CFRunLoop.c:3206)
10  GraphicsServices                0x00000001c4742534 GSEventRunModal + 108 (GSEvent.c:2246)
11  UIKitCore                       0x00000001be63d580 UIApplicationMain + 1940 (UIApplication.m:4773)
12  auction.ios                     0x00000001040e61c8 0x1040e0000 + 25032
13  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001ba330e18 start + 4
```

Comment: Look up how to symbolicate a crash log.  The address from frame "13  auction.ios" would be a likely hint if you translate it into a code reference.

Comment: try this solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358397/crash-when-running-on-device-after-second-launch

Answer (score 2):

if you are using MapKit in this xib then you have to add it to the frameworks, it seems an issue in xcode 11 . see this answer for more details [Crash when running on device after second launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358397/crash-when-running-on-device-after-second-launch) [image]